# Controller name randomly gets added to URLs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a controller class called `HomeController` and client javascript code like

```
function upload(content) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", 'UploadImage', false);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
    ajax.send(content);
}
```

Sometimes it works correctly using the URL `https://localhost/MyApp/Home/UploadImage` and uploads the data. But sometimes it fails because there's no controller name in the URL. Chrome developer tools shows the error as:

```
POST https://localhost/MyApp/UploadImage 404 ()
```

But if I insert /Home in the URL myself, changing the above code to

```
    ajax.open("POST", 'Home/UploadImage', false);
```

then sometimes it works and uses `https://localhost/MyApp/Home/UploadImage` but it sometimes fails with

```
POST https://localhost/MyApp/Home/Home/UploadImage 404 ()
```

If I recompile and start again, sometimes it changes to the opposite behavior but I can't predict when. The same thing happens with a GET request. I don't know if I should include the controller name `Home/` in my URLs or not. How can I make it behave consistently?

Comment: Try `/Home/UploadImage` instead of `Home/UploadImage`. You can also use Asp.NET url helpers to generate the link for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to relative URL only,

it will change with respect to code or page your using.. so solution for this is either u choose

```
ajax.open("POST", '/Home/UploadImage', false);
```

or

```
ajax.open('POST', '@Url.Action("UploadImage","Home")', false);
```

Comment: The random changes turned out to be VS opens the site at a different URL depending on which source file you have open when you press "run". If you're working on index.cshtml, it loads .../MyApp/Home/Index, otherwise just .../MyApp/.

Answer (score 1):

`UploadImage` is relative URL

```
location: localhost/MyApp/somepage.html => localhost/MyApp/UploadImage
location:  localhost/MyApp/Home/somepage.html => localhost/MyApp/Home/UploadImage
```

use `/MyApp/Home/UploadImage` or full URL if different domain